# Unable to convert string to byte if high-order bit is set

Tags: c#, string, byte

Apologies for the abortive first try, particularly to Olivier.  Trying again.
Situation is we have a string coming in from a mainframe to a C# app.  We understand it needs to be converted to a byte array.  However, this data is a mixture of ASCII characters and true binary UINT16 and UINT32 fields, which are not always in the same spot in the data.  Later on we will deserialize the data and will know the structure's data alignments, but not at this juncture.

Logic flow briefly is to send a structure with binary embedded, receive a reply with binary embedded, convert string reply to bytes (this is where we have issues), deserialize the bytes based on an embedded structure name, then process the structure.  Until we reach deserialize, we don't know where the UINTs are.  Bits are bits at this point.

When we have a reply byte which is ultimately part of a UINT16, and that byte has the high-order bit set (making it "extended ascii" or "negative", however you want to say it), that byte is converted to nulls.  So any value >= 128 in that byte is lost.

Our code to convert looks like this:

```
    public async Task<byte[]> SendMessage(byte[] sendBytes)
    {
        byte[] recvbytes = null;
        var url = new Uri("http://<snipped>");
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        webRequest.Timeout = 10000;

        using (Stream postStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            await postStream.WriteAsync(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            await postStream.FlushAsync();
        }
        try
        {
            string Response;
            int Res_lenght;
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
            using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
            {
                Response = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Res_lenght = Response.Length;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Response))
            {
                recvbytes = null;
            }
            else
            {
               recvbytes = ConvertToBytes(Response);
               var table = (Encoding.Default.GetString(
                                recvbytes,
                                0,
                                recvbytes.Length - 1)).Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
                                                        StringSplitOptions.None);
            } 
        }   
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //error    
        }
        return recvbytes;  

    }
    static byte[] ConvertToBytes(string inputString) 
    { 
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[inputString.Length * sizeof(byte)];
        String strLocalDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff");
        String fileName = "c:\\deleteMe\\Test" + strLocalDate;
        fileName = fileName + ".txt";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
        for (int i=0;i<inputString.Length;i++) {
            try
            {          
                outputBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(inputString[i]);
                writer.Write("String in: {0} \t Byte out: {1} \t Index: {2} \n", inputString.Substring(i, 2), outputBytes[i], i);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //error
            }
        }
        writer.Flush();
        return outputBytes; 
    }
```

ConvertToBytes has a line in the FOR loop to display the values in and out, plus the index value.  Here is one of several spots where we see the conversion error - note indexes 698 and 699 represent a UINT16:

String in: sp   Byte out: 32    Index: 696   << sp = space

String in: sp   Byte out: 32    Index: 697

String in: \0   Byte out: 0     Index: 698

String in: 2    Byte out: 50    Index: 700  << where is 699?

String in: 0    Byte out: 48    Index: 701

String in: 1    Byte out: 49    Index: 702

String in: 6    Byte out: 54    Index: 703

The expected value for index 699 is decimal 156, which is binary 10011100.  The high order bit is on.  So the conversion for #698 is correct, and for #700, which is an ascii 2 is correct, but not for #699.  Given the UINT16 (0/156) is a component of the key to subsequent records, seeing 0/0 for the values is a show-stopper.  We don't have a displacement error for 699, we see nulls in the deserialize.  No idea why the .Write didn't report it.

Another example, such as 2/210 (decimal 722 when seen as a full UINT16) come out as 2/0 (decimal 512).

Please understand this code as shown above works for everything except the 8-bit reply string fields which have the high-order bit set.

Any suggestions how to convert a string element to byte regardless of the content of the string element would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: A bit out of my element here, but I feel like the encoding the server used to construct the string's bytes is important to know. Also, UINT16 requires 2 bytes to be stored, so it makes sense that your first UINT16 is at index 698 and the next one should be at 700, not 699.

Comment: The encoding server is NonStop running a COBOL85 application.  We are converting byte-by-byte from string to byte array, not INT-by-INT.  The loop has no idea the bits it's looking at are anything but an 8-bit random pattern.  There is no way at this point in processing for it to know this is a UINT or char or what.  When the high order bit is NOT set, it converts perfectly well.

Comment: Quantic - to your point about the 2nd byte of a UINT, this is what we see when  0/10 is presented - indexes 44 and 45 are a UINT16: String in:  \0     Byte out: 0     Index: 44 
String in: x’0a’ Byte out: 10    Index: 45   << works fine
String in: sp     Byte out: 32    Index: 46

Comment: Oh I get it now, it must be an exception causing 699 to be missing, not that it somehow knew to read 2 bytes and "skipped" 699.

Answer (score 1):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to state specifically what is wrong. But given what you've posted, some useful observations can be made:

1. First and foremost, as far as *"where is 699?"* goes, it's obvious that an exception is being thrown. That's how the `WriteLine()` call would be skipped and result in no output for that index. You have a couple of opportunities in the code you posted for that to happen: the call to `Convert.ToByte()`, or the following statement (particularly the call to `inputString.Substring()`).

Unfortunately, without a good MCVE it's hard to understand why you are printing a two-character substring from the input string, or why you say the characters `"sp"` become the character value `0x20` (i.e. a space character). The output you describe in the question doesn't appear to be self-consistent. But, let's move on…

2. Assuming for the moment that at least in the specific case you're looking at, there are enough characters in `inputString` at that point for the call to `Substring()` to succeed, we're left with the conclusion that the call to `Convert.ToByte()` is failing.

Given what you wrote, it seems that the main issue here is a misunderstanding on your part about how text is encoded and manipulated in a C# program. In particular, a C# character is in some sense an abstraction and doesn't have an encoding at all. To the extent that you force the encoding to be revealed, i.e. by casting or otherwise converting the raw character value directly, that value is always encoded as UTF16.

Put another way: you are dealing with a C# `string` object, made of C# `char` values. I.e. by the time you get this text into your program and call the `ConvertToBytes()` method, it's already been converted to UFT16, regardless of the encoding used by the sender.

In UTF16, character values that would be greater than 127 (0x7f) in an "extended ASCII" encoding (e.g. any of the various ANSI/OEM/ISO single-byte encodings) are *not* encoded as their original value. Instead, they will have a 16-bit value greater than 255.

When you ask `Convert.ToByte()` to convert such a value to a `byte`, it will throw an exception, because the value is larger than the largest value that can fit in a `byte`.

It is fairly clear why the code you posted is producing the results you describe (at least, to some extent). But it is not clear at all what you are actually hoping to accomplish here. I can say that attempting to convert `char` values to/from `byte` values by straight casting is simply not going to work. The `char` type isn't a byte, it's two bytes and any non-ASCII characters will use larger values than can fit in a byte. You should be using one of the several .NET classes that actually will do text encoding, such as the `Encoding.GetBytes()` method.

Of course, to do that you'll have to make sure you first understand precisely why you are trying to convert to bytes and what encoding you want to use. The code you posted seems to be trying to interpret your encoded bytes as the current `Encoding.Default` encoding, so you should use that encoding to encode the text. But there's not really any value in encoding to that encoding only to decode back to a C# `string` value. Assuming you've done it correctly, all that will happen is you'll get exactly the same string you started with.

In other words, while I can explain the behavior you're seeing to the extent that you've described it here, that's unlikely to address whatever broader problem you are actually trying to solve. If the above does not get you back on track, please post a new question in which you've included a good MCVE and a clear explanation of what that broader problem you're trying to solve actually us.

Comment: The "sp" was my add to indicate a standard ascii space (hex 20) was read in.  Sorry to confuse.  This issue is readily and reliably repeated with every instance the high order bit is set.  That said, there is a parallel application written in C++ which has none of these issues.  So your point about C#s

Comment: encoding is likely where we are going wrong.  A parallel app in C++ has none of these issues.  C++ has more old-school field definitions where a char and a byte occupy 8 bits and a byte can hold up to 255.  An earlier iteration resulted in an array double expected size, and all bytes preceded by a null byte - sounds like UTF16 only we didn't know it.

Comment: That there is another program that works correctly tells you only that your program has bugs. Especially if that program is in C++, since C++ handles text _very_ differently than C#/.NET does. I've explained why the output is missing (you got an exception) and why you get an exception (the `char` value is larger than 255...this will always be the case when dealing with single-byte-encodings for characters in the "extended" range, i.e between 128 and 255).

Comment: How often we overlook the obvious.  Thanks for catching (pun intended) the exception code of "// error" which does exactly nothing!  Now I know what happened to 699......